# Python Function to convert temperature does not work properly

Tags: python, function, input

I am new in Python and I am doing an exercise in which I am supposed to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and viceversa. I am trying to do it trough a function which should process the user input and convert it. I am unfortunately stuck because it just partially works and I cannot understand where the problem is.  Here my code:

```
Temperature = int(input("Give an int as temperature"))

Unit = input("insert 'C' or 'F' as unit")

Mix_input = [(Temperature, Unit)] 



def convert_f_c(x):
    for t, u in x:
        if u == "C" or "c":
            F = round((1.8 * t) + 32)
            print("Converted Temp:{}F".format(F))
        elif u == "F" or "f":
            C = round((t-32)/ 1.8)
            print("Converted Temp:{}C".format(C))
        else:
            print("You typed something wrong")


convert_f_c(Mix_input)
```

If I enter a temperature in Celsius, it works as expected:

```
Give an int as temperature 60
insert 'C' or 'F' as unit c
Converted Temp:140F
```

But with the temperature in Fahrenheit, I get a wrong output:

```
Give an int as temperature 45
insert 'C' or 'F' as unit F
Converted Temp:113F
```

It happens also with lower case:

```
Give an int as temperature 45
insert 'C' or 'F' as unit f
Converted Temp:113F
```

the expected output would be:

```
Give an int as temperature 45
insert 'C' or 'F' as unit f
Converted Temp:7.2C
```

Also if I enter something different, I don´t get the error message: "You typed something wrong", as expected, but:

```
Give an int as temperature 145
insert 'C' or 'F' as unit r
Converted Temp:293F
```

Comment: you can change if like this `if u.lower() == 'c'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did:

```
if u == "C" or "c":
```

and

```
elif u == "F" or "f":
```

Due to [operator priority](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) these works actually as:

```
if (u == "C") or "c":
```

and

```
elif (u == "F") or "f":
```

as all non-empty string are truthy in python, these condition are always met. To avoid this you might do:

```
if u == "C" or u == "c":
```

or

```
if u in ["C", "c"]:
```

or

```
if u.lower() == "c":
```

(and same way with `elif`). `in` is membership, `lower` turn str into lowercase version.

Answer (score 1):

Change if `u == "C" or "c"` to `if u == "C" or  u== "c"`

just `or "c"` will always be truthy, which is why you get the error (same for `elif u == "F" or "f"`)